# Reset values in column A based on the value of column B using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a sheet that looks like this, but way more complex:

```
Product            count     real count
Rake Complete      -1        n/a
Rake Head          2         =B3+B2
Rake Handle        2         =B4+B2
Bike Complete      -5        n/a
Bike Handle        10        =B6+B5
Bike Wheel         25        =B7+B5+B5
Bike Frame         90        =B8+B5+B6
```

With the formulas working, it looks like this:

```
Product            count     real count
Rake Complete      -1        n/a
Rake Head          2         1
Rake Handle        2         1
Bike Complete      -5        n/a
Bike Handle        10        5
Bike Wheel         25        15
Bike Frame         90        85
```

I would appreciate help with VBA code that would reset the column B's value to the to be Column C's value like this:

```
Product            count    real count
Rake Complete      0        n/a
Rake Head          1        1
Rake Handle        1        1
Bike Complete      0        n/a
Bike Handle        5        5
Bike Wheel         15       15
Bike Frame         85       85
```

I have other VBA code that I put together on other sheets that add and subtract from the values in the `count` column. To keep this working inventory as accurate as I can and not based on a variable, I would like to reset column B everyday. That way, if a count is off slightly, I don't have to reset everything.

I have been working on this for awhile and I know there is a better way to do this than the five I have tried and failed at. It needs to be column based though, my sheet has 465 rows that this needs to apply to and as businesses grow, so will the rows on this sheet.

The code that got me the closest is this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Dim r As Long
    For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 2) = "n/a" Then Cells(r, 2).value = 0
    Next r

End Sub
```

The major problem I have is every time I run the code it ups the count on some of my other products.  If you look at the bike frame, you can sell it separately but you also get a bike handle when you do.  When this code resets it always adds the bike handles.  If I run it 10 times without changes my inventory grows higher then excel is willing to show. Any idea how I can fix this or any ideas of a different way all together?

Comment: =max(B2,0) in the "real count" column? I don't really understand what you are trying to do

Comment: please post what you have tried and failed at? We can help you much better if you show us what you've tried and is not working vs. just writing your code for you :)

Comment: Why don't you just copy column c and paste the values in column B?

Comment: That will mess up the values in column B that are next to "n/a" in column C

Comment: Also it needs to be VBA code.  I wont be the one using this program so I have to spell everything out for my boss.

Comment: I deleted several of the codes I tried to use.  I will apptempt to recreat the best this weekend.

Comment: Ok, the best program I have is up there but it has a glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste values - with a paste special - from column C to column B.

But then column C's values will obviously change - because Eistein and cause and effect or something like that.

Comment: That causes several other problems

Comment: Also it needs to be VBA code.  I wont be the one using this program so I have to spell everything out for my boss.

Comment: What other problems is it causing? you can easily automate a copy and paste with VBA - but it is such a basic operation - you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I updated the main post with the other problem this causes.  I know it involved more info than I first gave but I did say my real program is alot more complex.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use column D and call it Display Count, or something like that. Use this formula in column D:

```
=IF(C18="n/a", 0, C18)
```

You can then hide columns B and C if they confuse your boss.

[image: Display Count Column]

Comment: Good idea, but not what I am going for.  I want to reset the sheet at the end of the day so that we have a solid count and not a formula count.  I want to make it so that if he wants to change a count by clicking on it and updating a number he can.  then it would show the new count in the next cell and when we reset it will show the correct count back in the first cell.  An example would be if my boss sold a bike complete he can click b21, change the count and after hitting the end day button we would have the exact counts in column B and it would match column C.

Comment: Ok, I tinkered and this one works.  I can do a paste special and copy the values in Column D to Column B.  This allows an update everynight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro in the workbook open event. I hope it may solve your problem:

```
Dim realcount() As Variant
Dim x As Single

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   On Error Resume Next:
    x = Sheet1.Cells(2, 3).End(xlDown).Rows
    ReDim realcount(x)
    For i = 2 To x
        realcount(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = realcount(i)
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "n/a" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this code buy it didn't work at all.  The sad reason is I have no clue why it didn't work.  My computer didn't have a problem with it but it didn't change anything.  The only change I made to your program is replacing "Sheet1.Cells(i,  3).Value" and simular with "Sheets(count).cells(1,  3)Value".  Everything else was the same but it didn't effect my sheet at all.

Comment: I do not know why you changed the variables viz count and i. The correct code should have been Sheet1.Cells(i,3).value only where Sheet1 is the sheet number and i is the variable. Try it on only one sheet ie Sheet1 with variable i as it is and if it works extend it to other sheets or all the sheets.

Comment: All I did was rename the "sheet" so that I could try the code in a program I am already using.